# Capture ALL query parameters in GET request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a GET request with an endpoint looking like this:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tweets/alldata/?0=1&1=2

I know I can reach individual values with the key, but how do I capture ALL values in one variable?

I've tried it like this but nothing is captured at all:

```
followers = self.request.query_params.get('')
```

Comment: Have you check **`self.request.query_params`**?

Answer (score 1):

```
self.request.GET
```

Is a [dictionary-like object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) that contains all query parameters

It is immutable (can't be edited) but you can create a copy if you need a mutable object:

```
data = self.request.GET.copy()
```